# SDL driver fails when starting debug session on remote linux

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gdb, sdl, remote-debugging

On Win10, I have a visual studio c++ project for linux that uses the SDL2 driver. The target machine is a VirtualBox - Ubuntu 18.04.

I configured Visual studio to compile remotely on the target system, which works fine.
Running the output file from console on the remote machine shows that SDL uses the XServer:

```
SDL_GetCurrentVideoDriver: x11
```

When I start debugging from visual studio (starts GNU debugger gdb on remote side):

```
SDL_Init error: No available video device
SDL_GetCurrentVideoDriver: null
```

starting gdb from remote anyway works as expected:

```
gdb ./myProgram
(gdb) run
```

But this doesn't let me debug in visual studio, which i'm looking forward to. Any idea ?

Comment: See what the $DISPLAY environment variable is set to when you run it on the console. Set Visual Studio to set the variable the same way.

Comment: Remote debugging on Linux works through SSH.  It is by default configured to pass X11 through, and your Windows machine doesn't run an X server. Either disable the X11 pass-through at either side of the connection, or run X on Windows (this could be kinda slow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Project Settings:

`Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Pre-Launch Command -> export DISPLAY=:0`